# on_message not being triggered when using interactions.Client

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-interactions

I'm using *Interactions.py* (`client = interactions.Client`) so that I can use its sophisticated slash commands system, but as a result the `on_message` event method is no longer triggered.  When I use *Discord.py* (`client = discord.Client`) the `on_message` method works successfully.

How do I get `on_message` to work while using the slash command system of *Interactions.py*?

```
import os
import os.path
import interactions
import mysql.connector
import ast
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
import operator as op
import discord
import inspect
from math import sqrt
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents
intents.messages = True
client = interactions.Client(token=TOKEN)

@client.command(
    #command details here
)
async def count(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, command: str):
    #manage incoming commands
    #this only works correctly when I use client = interactions.Client

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #do things based on message contents
    #this only works correctly when I use client = discord.Client

client.Start()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the `interactions.py` has support for an `on_message` event the same way `discord.py` does?

Comment: Interactions are built-in to discord.py, why are you using a separate package for that?

Comment: @stijndcl Simply wasn't aware, haha.

Answer (score 1):

It would be `on_message_create`, as this is the name that the discord api uses